# WebDAV change password

Tags: webdav

I published my calendar successfully but my password has changed.

*Outlook Version:* 2010

*Platform:* Windows 7

How can I change the WebDAV password on the client side (Win 7)?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7 go to control panel and open Credential Manager.

Then edit or remove the credentials for your Outlook webdav login.